# R: Nothing was replaced using gsub() function

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, gsub

Hi I've tried to replace value of columns in data frame using the following code.

```
sampleNumber <- c(1:length(sampleId))
for (value in sampleNumber){
  genotypeCol <- paste("annotateData$", sampleId[value], sep = "") #sampleId is a vector contains column names in annotateData
  genotypeCol <- gsub("0\\/0", "ref", genotypeCol)
  genotypeCol <- gsub("0\\/1|0\\/2|0\\/3|1\\/2|1\\/3|2\\/3", "het", genotypeCol)
  genotypeCol <- gsub("1\\/1|2\\/2|3\\/3", "hom", genotypeCol)
}
```

Anyway, the content are still the same, but it works fine if I use the following code instead.

```
annotateData$Genotype_SM01 <- gsub("0\\/0", "ref", annotateData$Genotype_SM01)
annotateData$Genotype_SM01 <- gsub("0\\/0", "ref", annotateData$Genotype_SM01)
annotateData$Genotype_SM01 <- gsub("0\\/0", "ref", annotateData$Genotype_SM01)
```

So any ideas to for this issue.

Comment: Please provide a data example.

Comment: Note you may remove all ``\\`` from your patterns, `/` is not a special regex metacharacter and does not have to be escaped.

Comment: If you plan to replace each cell contents in the dataframe, you may discard the explicit loop and use `annotateData[] <- lapply(annotateData, function(x) gsub("0/0", "ref", x))`, `annotateData[] <- lapply(annotateData, function(x) gsub("0/[123]|1/[23]|2/3", "het", x))` and then `annotateData[] <- lapply(annotateData, function(x) gsub("([123])/\\1", "hom", x))`

Comment: Thanks for all comments, I'm quite new for programming. I'll try every suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding `gsub()` with a character string containing your variable name. To get the actual variable , use `get(paste("annotateData$", sampleId[value], sep = ""))`
**Edit**

```
aux=get("annotateData")
var=aux[,sampleID[value]]
```

In this case, `var` holds the value of `annotateData$Genotype_SM01`

**edit 2**
reworking your problem, the following code should do what you want.

```
annotateData=data.frame("Genotype_SM01"=c("a","a","b"),
                    "Genotype_SM02"=c("a","a","a"),
                    "Genotype_SM02"=c("b","b","a"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sampleId=names(annotateData)

sampleNumber <- c(1:length(sampleId))

for (value in sampleNumber){
  aux=annotateData[,sampleID[value]]
  aux <- gsub("0\\/0", "ref", aux)
  aux <- gsub("0\\/1|0\\/2|0\\/3|1\\/2|1\\/3|2\\/3", "het", aux)
  aux <- gsub("1\\/1|2\\/2|3\\/3", "hom", aux)
  annotateData[,sampleID[value]]=aux
}
```

Comment: As a tip, you can use `paste0()` instead of `paste( ... , sep="")`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's very useful for newbie like me :)

Comment: no problem! If this solution worked for you, remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got an error message:

`Error in get(paste0("annotateData$", sampleId[value])) : 
object 'annotateData$Genotype_SM01' not found`

Comment: you are right, it seems as `get()` cant access inside object. I updated my answer to work around.

Comment: Thanks boski, but this like extract the column from annotateData and do gsub(). The final output is a vector contains ref/het/hom values, it change nothing in annotateData. So is it possible to replace these values directly to annotateData?

Comment: Check my last edit. If you really wanted to work on the `annotateData` at all times, just change `aux` for `annotateData[,sampleID[value]]` on every `aux` instance, though I would not recommend this.

Comment: OMG, it works. Thanks for your kind help, your are savior for newbie like me :) This gonna be a good experiences.

Comment: we all start somewhere. Cheers.